# Serialization and deserialization of lambda

Tags: java, java-8

This code below throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.Subclass2 cannot be cast to test.Subclass1
at test.LambdaTest.main(LambdaTest.java:17)
```

---

```
public class LambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ToLongFunction<B> fn1 = serde((ToLongFunction<B> & Serializable) B::value);
        ToLongFunction<C> fn2 = serde((ToLongFunction<C> & Serializable) C::value);
        fn1.applyAsLong(new B());
        fn2.applyAsLong(new C()); // Line 17 -- exception here!
    }

    private static <T extends Serializable> T serde(T t) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(bos).writeObject(t);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos
                .toByteArray()));
        return (T) ois.readObject();
    }
}

class A {
    public long value() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class B extends A { }

class C extends A { }
```

The reason seems to be that after serialization and deserialization, both fn1 and fn2 end up as the same class. Is this a JDK/compiler bug or am I missing something about serialization and deserialization of lambdas?

Comment: Seems to be a caching bug? If you swap the first 2 lines in main, the cast exception is reversed.

Comment: There's another wrinkle here: if you add `ToLongFunction<C> cc = (ToLongFunction<C> & Serializable) A::value; cc.applyAsLong(new C());` *before* the serialization code in `main`, you get a CCE on the `fn1.applyAsLong` line. This seems to agree with @davidxxx's suggestion of caching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this Open JDK issue raised back in 2016:

[Deserialization of lambda causes ClassCastException](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154236)

It quite precisely matches your scenario:

> - Two (distinct) classes, `B` and `C`, both of which extend the same base class, `A`, which has a method, `String f()`.
> - Create a `Supplier` reference to method `f()` for an object of type `B`; call this `bf` [`new B()::f`].
> - Create a `Supplier` reference to method `f()` for an object of type `C`; cal this `cf` [`new C()::f`].
> - Serialize `cf` (`ObjectOutputStream#writeObject`)
> - When the serialized `cf` is deserialized (`ObjectInputStream#readObject`), a `ClassCastException` is thrown saying that class `C` cannot be cast to class `B`

There's an interesting discussion on the issue, but the very last comment by Dan Smith seems to nail it:

> Important observation for this particular test case: the "qualifying type" (i.e., the class named by the bytecode) of a method reference should be the same as the qualifying type of an invocation: the type of the receiver. javac is wrong to be using the type of the declaring class. See [JDK-8059632](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059632).
>
> Fix that bug, and I think the issue with different captured types goes away.

Comment: While Dan Smith is right in that fixing JDK-8059632 would also solve this particular example, it is possible to construct other examples which will still fail when only JDK-8059632 has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to explain that but the behavior is particular because executing the main code with only one invocation of `serde()` works for both cases.

That is this :

```
ToLongFunction<B> fn1 = serde((ToLongFunction<B> & Serializable) A::value);
fn1.applyAsLong(new B());
```

or this :

```
ToLongFunction<C> fn2 = serde((ToLongFunction<C> & Serializable) A::value);
fn2.applyAsLong(new C());
```

While as the two invocations are performed in the same program, I notice an expected thing :  the value of the parameter (`T t`) is not the same for the two cases.
But I notice an unexpected thing : at the second invocation of `serde()` the object returned by `ois.readObject()` is the same reference as which one returned by the first `ois.readObject()` invocation.
As if the first one was cached and reused for the second invocation.

It seems a bug.

Comment: "But I notice an unexpected thing" which is funny, because it's not the same instance being passed in. `System.err.println(t)` before the serialization shows that they're different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work, then remove the default implementation of `value()` from `BaseClass` interface and override it in the implementing classes like this:

```
interface BaseClass {
    long value();
}
public class LambdaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ToLongFunction<Subclass1> fn1 = serDe((Serializable & ToLongFunction<Subclass1>) Subclass1::value);
        fn1.applyAsLong(new Subclass1());
        ToLongFunction<Subclass2> fn2 = serDe((Serializable & ToLongFunction<Subclass2>) Subclass2::value);
        fn2.applyAsLong(new Subclass2());
    }

    private static <T extends Serializable> void printType(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    private static <T extends Serializable> T serDe(T t) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(bos).writeObject(t);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
        T readT = (T) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        bos.close();
        return readT;
    }
}
class Subclass1 implements BaseClass {

    @Override
    public long value() {
        return 0;
    }
}
class Subclass2 implements BaseClass {

    @Override
    public long value() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: A much less intrusive workaround is replacing method reference with lambda.